# UIViewControllerRepresentable content size changes when app returning from background

Tags: swiftui, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I have a SwiftUI simple application that presents `UIViewControllerRepresentable` that holds a `UIScrollView`.
When app goes to background and returns back, the layout of the scroll view changes.

```
struct FeedCategoryView: View {
  var viewModel: LandingFeedCategoryViewModel
  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
      RepresentableViewController()
      .frame(height: 287.8, alignment: .center)
      .foregroundColor(.gray)
    }
  }
}

struct RepresentableViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
  }

  func makeUIViewController(
    context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<FeedVC>
  ) -> UIViewController {
    return MyViewController()
  }
}
```